# Focus next NSTextField when tabing custom NSButton

Tags: macos, nstextfield

I have "next" and "previous" `NSButton` in view. When i click next button it will goes and focus(editable mode) next `NSTextField` and when i click "previous" button it will focus previous `NSTextfield`.

I have more than 25 to 30 `NSTextField` one by one. So it will be short cut way to solve this problem.

**Some keypoints:**
1."Next" and "Previous" button trigger like "Tab" and "shift+Tab" in our keyboard.

2."Next" button key value equalent to `"Tab"` and "previous" button key value equalent to `"shift+tab"`

I have tried below code but it'd work

```
[appDelegate.currentTextFieldFocussed.nextKeyView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please attach code snippets you have tried.Or link to working example might help.

Comment: i have already tried above code but it'd not working.